# Multiplying Rotation Matrices

Tags: matrices, rotations, quaternions

Let's say I have 2 Euler angles as vectors, **A=[96.708, 33.581, 52.147]** and **B=[45, 15, 30]**.

If I add these vectors together I get the Euler angle **C=[141.708, 48.581, 82.147]**.

When converting A and B to Quaternions in YXZ order I get:

**Q_A=\begin{bmatrix}w=0.666328498, x=0.726973335, y=-0.142010576, z=0.085726883\end{bmatrix}** and **Q_B=\begin{bmatrix}w=0.897692569, x=0.397692569, y=0.018283046, z=0.188823735\end{bmatrix}** such that:

**Q_A * Q_B = \begin{bmatrix}w=0.295455364, x=0.889210137, y=-0.218476201, z=0.272542859\end{bmatrix}**

This makes a 3x3 matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
    0.755977079 &-0.549591004 & 0.355595816 \\
    -0.227494005 & -0.729948556 & -0.644532066 \\
    0.613795677 & 0.406355552 & -0.676853036
\end{bmatrix}

However, it's different from the YXZ matrix and quaternion produced by the addition of the two vectors described above that become **C=[141.708, 48.581, 82.147]**:

\begin{bmatrix}
0.550717454 & -0.591865547 & -0.588562197 \\
-0.777502359 & -0.107237372 & -0.61966945 \\
0.303645135 & 0.798871279 & -0.519234352
\end{bmatrix}

Q_C = \begin{bmatrix}w=0.480688498, x=0.737765067, y=-0.464025734, z=-0.096547355\end{bmatrix}

What do I need to multiply Q_A * Q_B by in order to get Q_C if I were storing and working with only quaternions and not Euler angles?

Comment: Why do you want to add vectors of Euler angles? That process does not correspond to composition of rotations. The quaternion based handling of 3D-rotations is basically useful for making it easy to compose several rotations (and/or interpolate between them).

Comment: Rotations do not commute, so adding Euler angles does not make any sense in terms of rotations. Quaterions are fine but note that $Q_A * Q_B \neq Q_B * Q_A$

Comment: I’m aware and don’t want to add vectors, I’m asking what to multiply Q_A and Q_B by to get the same matrix that would be created by the addition of vectors. They create a different rotational movement in the 3D engine that I want to use in some situations, but as quaternions.

Comment: So you are looking for a $Q_I$ such that $Q_I*Q_A*Q_B=Q[A+B]$?

Comment: I wrote a Unity3D app to find the angle visually, and I get pretty close to it with [w=0.8732067,x=-0.3568831,y=-0.3188241,z=0.09217259] or the Euler angles [x=-34.4,y=-49.0,z=28.1]. Let's call it Q_X, so Q_A*Q_B*Q_X=Q_C. If matrix rotation multiplication and quaternion multiplication are isomorphic as some online texts say, and given that the transpose of any 3x3 non-scaled matrix should give its unit direction vectors, is there a more general formula to find any Q_A*Q_X=Q_B? This seems slightly related to the swing-twist decomposition, but I'm having trouble figuring out the smallest angles.

Comment: Although a pre-multiplied Q_I as user721481 asked would also be nice to know in such equations.